# call objective-c method from extern "C"

Tags: ios, objective-c, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have one temp.mm class which contains implementation for test class & extern "C" class. I am trying to call objective-c method in extern "c" class(i.e. testMethod & testMethod1).
How can i call objective-c method in extern "C" class function?.

I am new to Objective-c

I mention the example code below..

```
import<test.h>
@implement test

-(void)testMethod
{
//code
}

-(NSString*)testMethod1:(NSString *)value
{
   //code
   return value;
}

void callMethod()
{
   how to call testMethod & testMethod1 in this also?
}

@end

extern "C"
{
how to call testMethod & testMethod1?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C code part is (and must be) outside your class' implementation, so you'll have to create an object of `test` and then call it's methods, like follows:

```
void callMethod() 
{
    test *test = [[test alloc] init];
    [test testMethod];

    const char *yourCString = "yourCString";
    [test testMethod1:[NSString stringWithCString:yourCString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

You don't need the `extern "C"` part in the implementation (`.m` or `.mm` files), this is just needed in the header (`.h` files) when you want to mark them as "plain old c code" (not C++).

See: [Is it required to add 'extern C' in source file also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168241/is-it-required-to-add-extern-c-in-source-file-also)

Comment: thank you...i am trying to crate plugin for unity3d, because of that i want extern "C" part in implementation........that plugin contains web service(svc service) communication....

Comment: Ok, so why didn't you mention this in the first place? So I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30946257/2019384

Answer (score -1):

too call the method at initial .....
use:
[self testmethod];
[self testmethod1];
if you like to inherit this method in to another class just import the .m file.